# flash[:notice] or flash.notice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

FlashHash has convenience methods for :notice and :alert. My question then is, which is most appropriate? flash[:notice] or flash.notice? Is it simply a mater of taste or this there a compelling reason to chose one method over the other?

Answer (score 3):

```
# File actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb, line 150
150:       def notice
151:         self[:notice]
152:       end
```

I knew it!

Answer (score 2):

> Is it simply a mater of taste or this there a compelling reason to chose one method over the other?

Pretty much. `flash[:notice]` is how Rails handles it internally, so if there's a "right" way to do it, that's probably it. Personally, I prefer `flash.notice`, but that's just my own preference.

Comment: Pretty sure flash.notice, flash.debug, etc. are just convenience methods that end up calling flash[:notice], etc.

Comment: Yes, they are, hence "`flash[:notice] is how Rails handles it internally". I don't understand what point you're trying to make with your comment?